# Adobe Packager for iOS: Bundling native iOS code together with Flash?

Tags: flash, ios, packager-for-iphone

Is it possible to package native Objective C iOS code into a bundle (the same .ipa) created by the Adobe Flash Packager for iOS? I have an existing iOS application that I'd like to enhance with some existing Flash code. Is it possible to put these two components together in a single .ipa file and submit that package to the App Store as one application? Or must Adobe Packager apps contain pure Flash code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flash Packager cannot interface with custom Objective-C code.