# Can Haxe create library for iOS native method?

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, haxe

Flash packager can't [Adobe Packager for iOS: Bundling native iOS code together with Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584924/adobe-packager-for-ios-bundling-native-ios-code-together-with-flash)

Could Haxe do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To build iOS applications with Haxe you use the Haxe/C++ backend. Using this backend, you can write inline C++ if all else fails, so you can interface with pretty much anything native.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is definitely possible!

http://www.haxenme.org

NME has support for C, C++, Objective-C and Java code extensions. It is pretty easy to wire it up, so you can call it in Haxe just like any other method.

Here are some example extensions:

http://code.google.com/p/nme-extensions